# spring test with difference bean service

Tags: java, spring

I want to test service A, which has a method methodA1, A refers to a service B, which has a method methodB1,

In methodB1 is called in methodA1,

```
@Service
class A{
    @Autowired
    B b;
    void methodA1{
      ....
      b.methodB1();
      .....
    }
}

@Service
class B{

    void methodB1{
      ....
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test methodA1, but the methodB1 need to be overridden, so I create a new class BMock;

```
@Service("bMock")
class BMock execute B{
    @Override
    void methodB1{
    ....
    }
}
```

Test case like this:

```
class testClass extends springTest{

    @Autowired
    A a;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bMock")
    B b;

    @Test
    public void testMethodA1(){
        a.methodA1();
    }
}
```

actually, the methodA1 always call methodB1 in class B, I want it to call BMock in test case, how to do it?

Comment: Why not use frameworks like easymock/powermock/mockito etc to mock?

Comment: `@Qualifier("bMock")` is not going to do any thing (AFAIK) in this case. You interfaces. Instead of concreate `B b`use `AnInterfaceThatBImplements b`

Comment: @Shahzeb, Your means that i need to create a interface Ib, The class B and BMock implement interface Ib? if like this, the bMock will can be called in test case?

Comment: You could also use a test ApplicationContext, and define a mock service for B that gets created in this context (and your normal implementation does not). So your test will only have the mock implementation available for autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Re-Inject](https://github.com/sgri/spring-reinject) can be used to replace beans with mocks in test environment.

```
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ReInjectContext.class, testClass.TextContext.class})
 class testClass extends springTest {
    @Autowired
    A a;

    // Spring context has a bean definition for B, but it is     
    // overridden in the test's constructor, so BMock is created
    // instead of B. BMock gets injected everywhere, including A and the 
    // test
    @Autowired
    B b; 
    public testClass() {
           // Replace bean with id "b" with another class in constructor
           // "b" is bean ID that Spring assigns to B 
           ReInjectPostProcessor.inject("b", BMock.class);
    }

   @Test
   public void testMethodA1(){
      a.methodA1();
   }

    // If A and B are already the part of Spring context, this config
    // is not needed
    @Configuration
    static class TestContext   {
        @Bean public A a() {  return new A(); }
        @Bean public B b() {  return new B(); }
    }
 }
```

And remove @Qualifier and @Service from BMock

Answer (score 0):

If you have a setter for `b` in class A, override it explicitely in test :

```
class testClass extends springTest{

    @Autowired
    A a;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bMock")
    B b;

    @Test
    public void testMethodA1(){
        a.setB(b);
        a.methodA1();
    }
}
```

If you have no setter (and do not want to create it), you can use reflection :

```
Field bField = A.getDeclaredField("b");
fField.setAccessible(true);
fField.set(a, b);
```

it breaks isolation of private fields but may be acceptable for a test.